# How to catch OptimisticLockException and retry in JAX-RS?

Tags: jpa, ejb

I have some JAX-RS resources and they call inject `@EJB`'s methods.

And those methods can throw for Optimistic Lock timeout.

What type of exception(s) should I catch for retrying.

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException?

javax.ejb.EJBException?


class MyResource {

    @GET
    public Response doSomething() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    
            try {
                myEJB.doSomething();
                break;
            } catch (????) {
                // I just want to know the exact type of Exception
                // for lock wait timeout
            }
        }
    }

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;
}
```

Here comes the stack trace.

```
[#|2012-10-25T15:01:37.213+0900|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction|_ThreadID=193;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: UPDATE PLAYER_ACCOUNT SET BALANCE = ?, VERSION = ? WHERE ((((PLAYER_ID = ?) AND (ACCOUNT_TERM = ?)) AND (ACCOUNT_CURRENCY_ID = ?)) AND (VERSION = ?))
        bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: UpdateObjectQuery(kr.co.ticomms.gameground.persistence.PlayerAccount@46effcb6)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:749)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.updateObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1042)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1449)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3799)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1415)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1505)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3143)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:845)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at $Proxy245.depositPlayerAccounts(Unknown Source)
        at kr.co.ticomms.gameground.mobile.resources.__EJB31_Generated__PlayersResource__Intf____Bean__.depositPlayerAccounts(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at kr.co.ticomms.gameground.mobile.resources.Filter_.doFilter(Filter_.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:875)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
        ... 89 more
|#]

[#|2012-10-25T15:01:37.216+0900|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=193;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB PlayersResource, method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response kr.co.ticomms.gameground.mobile.resources.PlayersResource.depositPlayerAccounts(long,int,java.lang.Long)|#]

[#|2012-10-25T15:01:37.216+0900|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=193;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5142)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at $Proxy245.depositPlayerAccounts(Unknown Source)
        at kr.co.ticomms.gameground.mobile.resources.__EJB31_Generated__PlayersResource__Intf____Bean__.depositPlayerAccounts(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at kr.co.ticomms.gameground.mobile.resources.Filter_.doFilter(Filter_.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:473)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:845)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: UPDATE PLAYER_ACCOUNT SET BALANCE = ?, VERSION = ? WHERE ((((PLAYER_ID = ?) AND (ACCOUNT_TERM = ?)) AND (ACCOUNT_CURRENCY_ID = ?)) AND (VERSION = ?))
        bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: UpdateObjectQuery(kr.co.ticomms.gameground.persistence.PlayerAccount@46effcb6)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:749)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.updateObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1042)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1449)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3799)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1415)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1505)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3143)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:875)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
        ... 89 more
|#]
```

Comment: are you sure it is `Optimistic Lock timeout` or `LockTimeoutException`? Could you post cause stack trace?....

Comment: Actually no. A bunch of stack traces are telling `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lock Wait Timeout`, it is a `Pessimistic Locking`. Make supported lock modes ares :

1. PESSIMISTIC_READ - which represents a shared lock.
2. PESSIMISTIC_WRITE - which represents an exclusive lock.

`LockTimeoutException` is thrown when

1. An EntityManager instance try to do `PESSIMISTIC_READ` lock, another EntityManager holds `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock.
2. An EntityManager instance try to do `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock, another EntityManager holds `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock or `PESSIMISTIC_READ` lock.

You can configure timeout milliseconds with `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` in `persistence.xml`.

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="1000"/>
</properties>
```

For more reference [Locking in JPA](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock)

I am not sure you need to catch `OptimisticLockException` or not. But it is sure you will get `OptimisticLockException` if your entity used `@Version` annotation.